# Monitoring a process in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-services, monitoring, process

How can I monitor a Windows process and start it up if it is not running? I'd like to have something that starts up as a Windows service and can handle multiple processes.

**EDIT:**
Hopefully there's a ready to use library/component I can use and just tweak or configure instead of having to implement it from scratch. I know in the *nix world of two popular packages: god and monit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Windows Service that just watches the current process list.

[EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629(VS.85).aspx) provides the means of seeing processes running currently.  There are many APIs available to start a new process, including:

- system()
- _exec()
- WinExec()
- ShellExecute()/ShellExecuteEx()
- CreateProcess()
- CreateProcessAsUser()
- CreateProcessWithLogonW()

If you're using other languages/frameworks, they often provide their own wrappers around the above.

Comment: Do you know of anything that already does this (instead of having to reinvent the wheel)?

Comment: No.  However, it's pretty simple to do this in .NET languages - you can make a service that does this with probably <50 lines of code.  (Most of the above functions have high level wrappers in the System.Diagnostics namespace, like the Process class, which makes this trivial.)